# QGIS Fill Ring tool problem

Tags: qgis, digitizing

Using the new (in 2.2) 'Fill Ring' tool and it doesn't seem to work correctly in all cases. It seems that if I try and digitise the new ring close to the polygon boundary, TWO (or more) geometries will be created (and will get prompted to fill the attributes for), one for each adjacent polygon.

If I digitize the ring around the polygon center everything works fine.

Same behavior for shapefiles and Postgres layers that I tried.

The screenshot below shows an example. The attributes form displayed is the SECOND one and refers to the attributes of the polygon on the LEFT of the polygon I added the ring to.

[image]

Anyone got any ideas? Is this a bug?

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of what you are digitizing?

Comment: @underdark I edited the question with a screenshot

Comment: I can reproduce the creation of two new polygons by the fill ring tool if the underlying polygons overlap.

Comment: Problem is mine are not overlapping- ran the topology checker and at least around this area everything's fine- no overlaps. Try to create the ring close to the polygon boundary but w/out snapping to it.